# Do Activities as tabs get their onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState methods called on rotation?

Tags: android, tabs, rotation

Hi i currently have an Activity that hosts a tab view, and each tab is an Activity. The current problem i have is, on one of the activities(tab) i have some stuff i need to save on rotation, but it seems these methods dont get called when i change rotation, only on the activity that holds the tab view and launches each activity as a tab.

Here's the activity's onCreate method that holds the tabs:

```
LocalActivityManager mlam = new LocalActivityManager(this, false);
    tabs=(TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mlam.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tabs.setup(mlam);

    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MyProcessList.class);
    spec = tabs.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator((buildTabIndicator("Home")))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabs.addTab(spec);

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MyProcessList.class);
    spec = tabs.newTabSpec("artists2").setIndicator((buildTabIndicator("Menu")))
    .setContent(intent);

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MyProcessList.class);
    tabs.addTab(spec);
    spec = tabs.newTabSpec("artists2").setIndicator((buildTabIndicator("Options")))
    .setContent(intent);

    tabs.addTab(spec);


    tabs.setCurrentTab(0);`
```

The onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState methods in the same class:

```
    @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {

    bundle.putString(BOB,"ola");

}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {

    String hi=bundle.getString(BOB);
    System.out.println(hi);


}
```

But the activity as a tab(MyProcessList) own onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState methods dont seem to get called...is there a way around this?

regards,

Here's the warning i get when using the methods in the MainMenu activity:

```
05-11 12:15:16.017: W/Bundle(32053): Key BOB expected Bundle but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
```

05-11 12:15:16.033: W/Bundle(32053): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
05-11 12:15:16.033: W/Bundle(32053): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.os.Bundle
05-11 12:15:16.033: W/Bundle(32053):    at android.os.Bundle.getBundle(Bundle.java:1142)
05-11 12:15:16.033: W/Bundle(32053):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.dispatchCreate(LocalActivityManager.java:455)
05-11 12:15:16.033: W/Bundle(32053):    at sinfic.mobile.ipdms.MainMenu.initActivity(MainMenu.java:66)
05-11 12:15:16.033: W/Bundle(32053):    at sinfic.mobile.ipdms.core.IpdmsCoreActivity.onCreate(IpdmsCoreActivity.java:38)
05-11 12:15:16.033: W/Bundle(32053):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-11 12:15:16.033: W/Bundle(32053):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-11 12:15:16.033: W/Bundle(32053):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
05-11 12:15:16.033: W/Bundle(32053):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-11 12:15:16.033: W/Bundle(32053):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3351)
05-11 12:15:16.033: W/Bundle(32053):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-11 12:15:16.033: W/Bundle(32053):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
05-11 12:15:16.033: W/Bundle(32053):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-11 12:15:16.033: W/Bundle(32053):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-11 12:15:16.033: W/Bundle(32053):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-11 12:15:16.033: W/Bundle(32053):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-11 12:15:16.033: W/Bundle(32053):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-11 12:15:16.033: W/Bundle(32053):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-11 12:15:16.033: W/Bundle(32053):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-11 12:15:16.033: W/Bundle(32053):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

its refering to:
mlam.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to call super also.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    // SAVE YOUR DATA IN "outState"
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    //RECOVER YOUR DATA FROM "savedInstanceState"
}
```

Comment: Are those calls in that order regarding the save /restore data?

Comment: yep doesnt seem to be working, but i assume you mean to put these in the activity as tab right???actually i put them on both classes, but only the activity with the tab view is getting these methods called...